# incorrect JARs for Casbah in Scala?

Tags: eclipse, scala, mongodb, jar, casbah

```
import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._
val newObj = MongoDBObject( "abc" -> 1, "def" -> 2 )
```

This gives me the following error:

"class file needed by ValidDateOrNumericTypeHolder is missing. reference value joda of package org refers to nonexisting symbol."

I googled around to resolve this error, but wasn't successful. Can someone please guide me ?

I am running this in Eclipse Java EE with Scala 2.9.0 plugin. I have the following referenced libraries in my Eclipse project.

casbah-commons_2.9.0-1-2.1.5-1.jar

casbah-gridfs_2.9.0-1-2.1.5-1.jar

casbah-core_2.9.0-1-2.1.5-1.jar

casbah-query_2.9.0-1-2.1.5-1.jar

casbah-dynamic_2.9.0-1-2.1.5.0.jar

mongo-1.0.jar

mongo-java-driver-2.7.1.jar

mongo-driver_2.9.0-1-0.2.0.jar

Follow-up Question:

Having fixed the above problem with Antoine's guidance, I moved on and tried the following:

```
newObj( "abc" )
```

and got this error:

java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class com.mongodb.BasicDBObject does not implement the requested interface org.bson.BSONObject

Any idea how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably need to add the [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) jar to your classpath

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, Antoine. Your pointer was indeed helpful.

I had to add the following JARs to get this to work:

slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar

joda-time-2.1.jar

slf4j-simple-1.6.4.jar

scalaj-collection_2.9.1-1.2.jar